# Refused to apply style from 'cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/owl.carousel.min.js' andstrict MIME checking is enabled

Tags: javascript

Refused to apply style from 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/owl.carousel.min.js' because its MIME type ('application/javascript') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.

Answer (score 0):

For those of you still searching an answer,try changing the link rel to script tag:

replace:
<
link rel='stylesheet' href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/owl.carousel.min.js'/>

to :
<
script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/owl.carousel.min.js'>